# Replacement Help, Patterns, Rules?

Tags: replacement

---

I have been trying to replace multiples of one thing in an expression, for example:

(E^(4 s - 2 z) + E^(8 s - 4 z) + E^(12 s - 6 z)) //. {(4 s - 2 z) -> 
   meow}

### However, I end up with the output of E^meow + E^(12 s - 6 z) + E^(8 s - 4 z), where as I would like it to be E^meow + E^(2 meow) + E^(3 meow) instead.

Also I would like to replace the following 
(g_1 + g_2 + g_3 + g_4) /. {g_1 -> h1, g_2 -> h2}. However, I would like it be a pattern for so it replaces all g_# to h# instead.

### Note: by g_# I mean a subscript #

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am sorry I cannot really give much more info, as I dont really know much about mathematica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[s, z]
FullSimplify[E^(4 s - 2 z) + E^(8 s - 4 z) + E^(12 s - 6 z),  w == 4 s - 2 z] /. w -> meow
```

> E^meow (1 + E^meow + E^(2 meow))

```
ExpandAll @ %
```

> E^meow + E^(2 meow) + E^(3 meow)

For the second part of the question:

```
expr = Plus @@ Array[Subscript[g, #] &, 4]
```

> Subscript[g, 1] + Subscript[g, 2] + Subscript[g, 3] + Subscript[g, 4]

```
TeXForm @ expr
```

> $g_1+g_2+g_3+g_4$

```
expr /. Subscript[a_, b_] :> Symbol["h" <> ToString[b]]
```

> h1 + h2 + h3 + h4

Comment: Thank you very much!! I greatly appreciate it!!!!

Comment: @CabbageLord, you are welcome. Thank you for the accept. And welcome to mma.se.